# Как заставить работать :before и :after в ie9?

Tags: html, css

Все пишут, что работает, но когда я открываю сайт через ie9 там `before` и `:after` не пашет.

Comment: Вот это вставили в начало странички? <!doctype html>

Comment: Да вставил <!doctype html>

Comment: In quirks mode, IE 9 does not support the old one-colon notations  :after and :before either. It supports them (but not the two-colon versions) in “IE 8 mode”, which you can select in developer tools (F12) manually, in the “document mode” menu, or at document level using the tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте ::before, ::after ;)

Comment: Попробовал, ситуация таже)

Comment: Скиньте адрес страницы, и действительно - к каким элементам пытаетесь применить?

Comment: Возможно ли вместо <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> написать <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> ? Попробуйте, просто IE=8 включает эмуляцию IE8, если так можно выразиться )

Comment: заменил, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Изначально этой строки там вообще не было, я добавил ее после первого комментария, посмотреть изменится ли что-нибудь

Comment: @harley, проверил сейчас в IE( правда 11, но с эмуляцией 9), картинки к ссылкам ( именно они у вас в псевдоэлементе, как я понял ) отображаются. В инспекторе :before нет, но в правилах стиля видно, что псевдоэлемент есть.

Comment: @harley, давайте так - мы видим вообще одну и ту же картину? Вот прям IE9 http://tinypic.com/r/df8utj/8 с выделенной ссылкой и применённым стилем

Comment: Вот я открываю через ie9: http://i59.tinypic.com/14jt5eg.jpg, картинки над пунктами меню не отображаются

Comment: Это точно чистый IE? а то какие-то бордеры и картинка в шапке типа есть, но не подгружена.. может даже просто ссылки битые? что говорит вкладка network?

Comment: Спасибо большое, ситуация разрешилась, оказалось на том компе где ie9 торчал, режим документа просмотра смотрелся через ie7...

Answer (score 0):

С какими элементами пытаетесь вывести after/before? Эти псевдоэлементы поддерживают только теги, где есть "внутренности": `div`, `p`, `select`
А вот с некоторыми `input` он работать не будет, так же как и с `img`

Comment: к ссылкам меню и к div пременяю